# Getting Error while invoking lambda function from another lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

While invoking Lambda function from another lambda function, I am getting this error

```
User: arn:aws:sts::34566842343:assumed-role/Lambda_Invoke/actions is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-1:34566842343:function:main because no identity-based policy allows the lambda:InvokeFunction action.
```

I also give lambda Invoke permission to my IAM user nevertheless I am getting this error.

Comment: "I also give lambda Invoke permission to my IAM user" what IAM user? You should be giving that permission to the IAM **Role** that is assigned to the Lambda function, not an IAM user.

Comment: After you fixed that IAM role permission issue, I'd suggest to use stepFunctions rather than chained lambda functions. It is not a best practice to have lambda calling another lambda since the lambda that is calling the other lambda will wait and generate billing for nothing...

Comment: @MarkB I appreciate your support. I am a self-learner who is new to AWS, which is why I became confused after reading certain articles.

Comment: @AnthonyB. that's only true if the first Lambda is invoking the second one in request/response mode. There are perfectly valid system designs that have one Lambda calling another one directly, without the use of Step Functions.

Comment: @AnthonyB. Thank you for your advice. I'm new to AWS, so I'll explore stepfunctions and try to implement in the manner you describe.